# JS reduce: object accumulator titles

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I am experimenting with the reduce function at the moment and wondering if I can tailor the accumulator's keys' name to be a specific value?

For example, the below code returns {16 years of experience: ... } but I would like the return results to be categorized like the below:

```
Results wanted in this format:

{ Over 10 years:
  16: {
    {name: "Company One", category: "Finance", start: 1981, end: 2003},
    {name: "Company Two", category: "Retail", start: 1992, end: 2008}

  },


  20: { 
  {name: "Company One", category: "Finance", start: 1981, end: 2003},
  {name: "Company Two", category: "Retail", start: 1992, end: 2008}
  }

  ...
} etc...


const companies = [
    {name: "Company One", category: "Finance", start: 1981, end: 2003},
    {name: "Company Two", category: "Retail", start: 1992, end: 2008},
    {name: "Company Three", category: "Auto", start: 1999, end: 2007},
    {name: "Company Four", category: "Retail", start: 1989, end: 2010},
    {name: "Company Five", category: "Technology", start: 2009, end: 2014},
    {name: "Company Six", category: "Finance", start: 1987, end: 2010},
    {name: "Company Seven", category: "Auto", start: 1986, end: 1996},
    {name: "Company Eight", category: "Technology", start: 2011, end: 2016},
    {name: "Company Nine", category: "Retail", start: 1981, end: 1989}
  ];
  

const industryExeperience = (obj, keyStart, keyEnd)=>{
  return obj.reduce((exp, curObj)=>{
    let differences = curObj[keyEnd] - curObj[keyStart];
    console.log(differences)
    if(differences > 10){
      exp[differences + ' years of experience'] = curObj

    }
    return exp
  },{})
}

console.log(industryExeperience(companies, 'start', 'end'))
```

Comment: Grouping criteria isn't totally clear. You want root groups of decades perhaps with each having group by years? What is your higher level use case, that might help to understand

Comment: I wanted to group the difference between companies.end - companies.start, and that would represent the years of experience. Then I wanted to use reduce to see if I can return the accumulator where I can say "hey for a group of companies over 10 years, here they are!" and once you decompress it, you'll see the companies.. etc. I feel like its doable but I just dont have the experience to know i guess? haha

Comment: Sounds like all you really need is use `filter()` as needed. For 10-20 years would be `arr.filter(({start, end}) => end-start >= 10 && end-start <=20)`

Comment: yea, but the problems are the keys, where does 20 come from or is it a pattern of  divisors by 4?

Comment: @EugenSunic The numeric keys come from `end-start`

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl ! Filter does work but I also want to see if I can do that in reduce. And Eugen Sunic, the 20 is what I am trying to get to as well. Even though there is no "perfect" 20 from the differences in the objects I provided. I want to see if I can make that into the accumulator object so that it can display {20: {name: company x...}, {name: company y}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group by years use the difference as keys and an array as values.
Push or concat each item into existing array or add new one as needed

```js
const companies = [
    {name: "Company One", category: "Finance", start: 1981, end: 2003},
    {name: "Company Two", category: "Retail", start: 1992, end: 2008},
    {name: "Company Three", category: "Auto", start: 1999, end: 2007},
    {name: "Company Four", category: "Retail", start: 1989, end: 2010},
    {name: "Company Five", category: "Technology", start: 2009, end: 2014},
    {name: "Company Six", category: "Finance", start: 1987, end: 2010},
    {name: "Company Seven", category: "Auto", start: 1986, end: 1996},
    {name: "Company Eight", category: "Technology", start: 2011, end: 2016},
    {name: "Company Nine", category: "Retail", start: 1981, end: 1989}
  ];
  
const grouped = companies.reduce((a,c)=>{
    const diff = c.end - c.start;
    a[diff] = (a[diff] || []).concat(c)
    return a;
},{})

console.log(grouped)
```